# Mixing creation and migration scripts with Flyway

Tags: flyway

Can Flyway be used to mix creation and migration scripts so that:

- new installations run a schema creation script
- existing installations run migration scripts, and never see the creation scripts of subsequent versions

?

E.g. given:

```
db/create/V1/V1__schema.sql
db/create/V2/V2__schema.sql
db/create/V3/V3__schema.sql
db/migration/V1/V1.1__migrateA.sql
db/migration/V2/V2.1__migrateB.sql
db/migration/V2/V2.2__migrateC.sql
```

An existing V1 installation would run the following to get to V3:

- db/migration/V1/V1.1__migrateA.sql
- db/migration/V2/V2.1__migrateB.sql
- db/migration/V2/V2.2__migrateC.sql

It would never run the following, as these represent schema-only SQL produced by mysqldump:

- db/create/V2/V2__schema.sql
- db/create/V3/V3__schema.sql

A new V3 installation would run:

- db/create/V3/V3__schema.sql

The above conflicts with the approach recommended by [Upgrade scenario when using Flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544831/upgrade-scenario-when-using-flyway) but is required as data is populated independently of the migration.

It looks like it should be possible to use flyway.locations to support this, but installations would always need to include the path to their creation script so that Flyway can see it.

The alternative appears to be to run the creation scripts outside of Flyway and set a baseline, but it would be nice if Flyway could manage everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I developed a tool to do this.
The tool has the latest schema in:

```
db/schema/schema.sql
```

and the migration scripts in:

```
db/migration/<version>/<version>.<sequence>__<JIRA issue>.sql
```

e.g.:

```
db/migration/V1/V1.1__JIRA-15.sql    
db/migration/V2/V2.1__JIRA-12.sql
db/migration/V2/V2.2__JIRA-22.sql
db/migration/V3/V3.0__JIRA-34.sql
```

If the database has no tables, schema.sql is executed, and then flyway is baselined with the most recent version, as reported by Flyway's 
    **MigrationInfoService.pending()** method.

i.e. the last MigrationInfo element returned by **pending()** determines the version to pass to **Flyway.setBaselineVersion()** before invoking **Flway.baseline()**
e.g:

```
DbSupport support = DbSupportFactory.createDbSupport(connection, true);
Schema schema = support.getOriginalSchema();
if (schema.allTables().length == 0) {
  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("db/schema/schema.sql", getClass().getClassLoader());
  SqlScript script = new SqlScript(resource.loadAsString("UTF-8"), support);
  script.execute(support.getJdbcTemplate());
  MigrationInfo[] pending = flyway.info().pending();
  MigrationInfo version = pending.length > 0 ? pending[pending.length - 1] : null;
  if (version != null) {
    flyway.setBaselineVersion(version.getVersion());
    flyway.setBaselineDescription(version.getDecription());
    flyway.baseline();
  }
}
```

This ensures that none of the migration scripts are invoked for newly created databases, but does mean that schema.sql must already contain all of the changes.

If the database has tables, but no Flyway information, it is baselined according to the detected schema version.